# Ternary operator multiple actions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, return, conditional-operator

I'm using Antd table and filtering student's data by applying a range filter on age column. I've marks and attendance columns also in my table. After filter my result is also fetching data from marks and attendance columns as well which I want to disable.

I'm using ternary operator and what I tried I'm sharing below:

```
// SHOWING RESULT(S) FOR IN-BETWEEN RANGE FOR AGE ONLY WHEN SEARCHED

const handleSearch = (firstInput, secondInput) => {
  setSearchStu(
    student.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.age >= firstInput && obj.age <= secondInput
        ? (true, xxxxxxxxxxxx)
        : obj.marks >= firstInput && obj.marks <= secondInput
        ? (true)
        : obj.attendance >= firstInput && obj.attendance <= secondInput
        ? (true)
        : false;
    })
  );
};
```

`xxxxxxxxxxxx` means at this point I want to disable marks and attendance columns from filtering themselves when search is being done for age column only and vice-versa.

I tried by writing something like (true, (obj.attendance: false)) : and so on.. but it's throwing syntax error for : and ) .

What should I put at `xxxxxxxxxxxx` to get my desired result? Or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: you can't use `(true, xxxx)` or `(true)`, the `(...)` is no data structure in JS - it is invalid syntax, `(...)` is used for creating a `tuple` in `python`

Comment: if I'm not wrong we can do something like (true, xxxx) in reactjs when we want to do multiple actions when a condition comes true.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you only want to filter by `age` and not `marks` and `attendance`. In that case you just need to get the new filtered array and set the state using `setSearchStu` function. Here is the code:

```
const handleSearch = (firstInput, secondInput) => {
  const newFilteredStudents = student.filter((obj) => obj.age >= firstInput && obj.age <= secondInput);
  setSearchStu(newFilteredStudents);
};
```

Comment: RishabhGupta, thanks for the reply. But FYI I've to use all 3 columns(age, marks and attendance) at a time but the search should be performed only at one at a time. Any assistance for this?

Comment: How do you determine on which parameter (age, marks or attendance) should the search be performed on?

Comment: RishabhGupta,, I've set search filter on every column(age, marks or attendance) which basically takes 2 inputs i.e. to filter data in-between range of given these 2 inputs.

Comment: if you want to apply filter to all the columns then you just need to extend the filter by adding more conditions by using `and` condition `&&`